# How do I run a specific test within junit

Tags: maven, junit

We have several junit test cases in a particular file, how do I run a certain test alone.

Note: I am aware of the `@Ignore` annotation, but don't want to use it. Since you will still have to mark the rest of the use cases with the `@Ignore` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the test you would like to run via the `-Dtest=` parameter.
Just run it with this parameter values:

```
-Dtest=TestClass#singleTestCaseMethod
```

It is only supported in JUnit 4.x. More information: [Running a single test](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how you're running the tests.

If you're using Eclipse, you can either select the name of the method in the Java Editor and press <kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to Run As JUnit. This also works if the cursor is on the method name itself.

If you've already run the tests, and the JUnit view is open in Eclipse, you can rerun a particular method by right clicking on the test and selecting `Run/Debug`. There will be similar functionality in Intellij.

[image]

If you're running from the command line, you can use [JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html).

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 TestClass2
```

EDIT: For maven, you can specify the name of the method on the command line:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test
```

See the documentation for [Maven Surefire - Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).

Comment: forgot to mention, that I use maven test -Dtest=... to run a test

Comment: @priya Please edit your question, so that includes this information. This makes it easier, why this answer is not suitable to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (You should try the free community edition, I tried several IDE and I found IntelliJ to be the best, far ahead the competition), you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to run unit tests. The location of the cursor will decide what to run: if it's within a test, it will run this test only, if it's outside, it will run all the tests on the current class.

And <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> will re-run whatever was last ran.

You can also right-click on the `Run` view to re-run any specific test.

Comment: forgot to mention, that I use maven test -Dtest=... to run a test